# System of second order ode

Tags: system, sympy, ode

I am trying to solve an IVP, consisting of two second order ode. I use sympy. No problems to obtain general solution. But I don't understand how to plug in the IC:s.
MWE:

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x1,x2=symbols('x1,x2',cls=Function)
t,k1,k2,m1,m2=symbols('t k1 k2 m1 m2',real=True)
k1=1.0
k2=1.0
m1=1.0
m2=1.0
eq1=Eq(m1*diff(x1(t),t,2)+k1*x1(t)-k2*(x2(t)-x1(t)),0)  
eq2=Eq(m2*diff(x2(t),t,2)+k2*(x2(t)-x1(t)),0)  
eqs=[eq1,eq2]
IC1={x1(0):0,x1(t).diff().subs(t,0):0}
IC2={x2(0):1,x2(t).diff().subs(t,0):0}
sol=dsolve(eqs,[x1(t),x2(t)],ics=[IC1,IC2])
print(sol)
```

Error message:

```
for funcarg, value in ics.items():

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: The ics parameter should be a single dict with all the initial condition equations rather than a list of two dicts.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get an error, Here is my modified code:  sol=dsolve(eqs,[x1(t),x2(t)],ics=x1(0):0,x1(t).diff().subs(t,0):0,x2(0):1,x2(t).diff().subs(t,0):0)
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You need `{` and `}` around the dict key, value pairs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Thanks, but not 100 % accomplished. So here is modified code, according to your hint: ol=dsolve(eqs,[x1(t),x2(t)],ics={x1(0):0,x1(t).diff().subs(t,0):0,x2(0):1,x2(t).diff().subs(t,0):0}) And the output as follows: [Eq(x1(t), 2.61803398874989*C2*sin(0.618033988749895*t) - 1.0*C2*sin(1.61803398874989*t) + 0.447213595499959*cos(0.618033988749895*t) - 0.447213595499959*cos(1.61803398874989*t)), Eq(x2(t), 4.23606797749978*C2*sin(0.618033988749895*t) + 0.618033988749895*C2*sin(1.61803398874989*t) + 0.72360679774998*cos(0.618033988749895*t) + 0.276393202250022*cos(1.61803398874989*t))]

Comment: So, two of four constants are still indetermined. Have you any smart hints, Oscar?

Comment: It is generally better to avoid the use of floats e.g. `1` rather than `1.0` but that doesn't seem to be the problem here. Maybe a bug so best to report on GitHub. https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: There is something degenerate maybe about the solution or the system. The solution for x1 does seem to satisfy both initial conditions regardless of having a C2 in there. However the solution for x2 does not satisfy the derivative condition unless C2 is zero so it should have been found to be zero.